# populate an uitableview from a nsdictionary

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have a nsdictionary from a json which responses that:

```
({
    email = "something@gmail.com";
    name = "User1";
},
    {
    email = "something2@gmail.com";
    name = "user2";
})
```

This is my code in de .m file:

```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{



    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;

    int errorCode = httpResponse.statusCode;

    NSString *fileMIMEType = [[httpResponse MIMEType] lowercaseString];

    NSLog(@"response is %d, %@", errorCode, fileMIMEType);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    //NSLog(@"data is %@", data);

    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(@"string is %@", myString);
    NSError *e = nil;

    usersDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

    NSLog(@"dictionary is %@", usersDictionary);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {



    // inform the user

    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",

          [error localizedDescription],

          [[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

   NombreUsuario = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[usersDictionary count]];


}
```

I use this to return the numbers of rows in section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [usersDictionary count];
}
```

But I don't realize how to put the pair of data email,name into a tableview in which each cell have to show the main label for the name, and the subtitle for the email.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The JSON you show is an array of dictionaries... What is your specific problem?

Comment: This is really a basic question. Given you're realizing that you got an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects (as Wain pointed out already) which is a perfect fit for a table view data source, you'll find an answer here: [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html), especially chapter "A Closer Look at Table View Cells".

Comment: Well, sorry for asking such a basic question, but I cannot find how to obtain the nsarray from de dictionary, I always geo an "[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" I don't really know how to deal with that, and I have been reading all the web for two days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question for future reference for who may need it.

First I had to store the json response in an NSMutableArray instead of an dictionary.

As I have an array of dictionaries I have two levels of information, I was trying to decompose it into new objects, but it wasn't the proper approach, so to access the second level I have to navigate to it:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[NombreUsuario objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
```

With this [NombreUsuario objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] I access the first level of information, and then with objectForKey:@"name" I get all the values that match the key "name".

For the detail label text is the same:

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NombreUsuario objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"email"];
```

Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write your code for you, but you need to look at how to implement a [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In particular, what you are looking to do will be within the - tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. There are thousands of good examples on the Internet for you.

Comment: I know how to populate a tableview, what I don't know is how to deal with an array of dictionaries.